# How to give isset on get_cat_id ($up_options->category1)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code like this (call a category defined from theme panel):

```
 <?php query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=1&cat='.get_cat_id
 ($up_options->category1)
 );
```

Everything work fine but need to add isset in case the category did not define.

I give isset like this:

```
 <?php query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=1&cat='.get_cat_id(
 (isset($up_options->category1) && $up_options->category1))
 );
```

But did not work.
Can anyone help me?  I'm pretty new to PHP.

Thank for any kind of helps.

Here the full code:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <?php query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=1&cat='.get_cat_id($up_options->category1));    
     if (have_posts()) :
         while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <div class="inside">
        <div class="title">
            <h5> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php  the_title(); ?>"><?php echo substr(the_title('', '', false), 0, 75); ?>...</a> </h5>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$cat_id = get_cat_ID($up_options->category1);

if($cat_id != null){
    query_posts('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=1&cat='.$cat_id);
} else {
    echo 'Category not defined';
}
```

**Update**

Here is working solution according to updated question:

```
<?php 
    global $up_options;
    $cat_id = get_cat_ID($up_options->category1);

    if($cat_id != null) :
        query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=1&cat='.$cat_id);    
         if (have_posts()) :
             while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="title">
                <h5>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php  the_title(); ?>"><?php echo substr(the_title('', '', false), 0, 75); ?>...</a>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>
     <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); endif;?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 5. Line 5 is $cat_id

Comment: I tested same code and it works fine for me. Can you share your code?

Comment: Check updated answer.. I tested it and it works fine

Comment: Need isset on $up_options->category1. With your new code from you, the result is not different with my first code. Still get error when the category not define.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. This code shows post if category is defined and doesn't show anything if there is no category. What error you get? Same as in first comment again?

Comment: When the category not define, get this notify "Trying to get property of non-object in D:\SERVER\wordpress\wp-content\themes\rocktest\header.php on line 4." Line 4 is $cat_id = get_cat_ID($up_options->category1);

Comment: In upthemes framework `$up_options` needs to be called before you can use it. Try adding `global $up_options;` above `$cat_id` like in updated answer. If that doesn't work then you'll have to create function with all this and call it where you need it. Example here https://github.com/UpThemes/UpThemes-Framework/issues/18